# Disable different month from start date in datepicker react js

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, disable

I want to ask about how to disable other month if they are different from the start date.
So, i choose start date at "10-01-2021" other month like 02 (February) until 12 (December) will disable on datepicker.
I'm so confuse how to set it on React.JS

This is my datepicker code :

```
 <DatePicker
              calendarClassName="tren-pembayaran__wrapper__datepicker"
              dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
              placeholderText="Tahun Awal"
              selected={startDate}
              minDate={new Date("2020")}
              onChange={(date) => onStartDateChange(date)}
            />
            <DatePicker
              calendarClassName="tren-pembayaran__wrapper__datepicker"
              dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
              placeholderText="Tahun Akhir"
              minDate={startDate}
              selected={endDate}
              onChange={(date) => onEndDateChange(date)}
            />
```

Hope you can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Can i ask about how are you setting "day"? Because in the mode that you are using this DatePicker - you can only set Month and Year.

Comment: Oh my God, I'm sorry I paste the wrong codes

Comment: I was edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<DatePicker>` component has a [maxDate](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-max-date) property. So you need to add 1 more variable that will be updated on the `startDate` change and will hold the "last day of the selected month". `useMemo` ideally works for that.

Updates requested in comments:

For 2 modes of DatePickers you will need 2 useMemo variables. For first mode - maxDate will be the endOfCurrentMonth. For second one - endOfCurrentYear.

Additianlly added a `useEffect` to reset `endDate` when `startDate` changes, remove if not needed.

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();
  const minStartDate = useMemo(() => {
    return new Date("2020");
  }, []);

  const startDateEndOfMonth = useMemo(() => {
    if (!startDate) return undefined;
    const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(
      startDate.getFullYear(),
      startDate.getMonth() + 1,
      0,
      23,
      59,
      59
    );
    return lastDayOfMonth;
  }, [startDate]);

  const startDateEndOfYear = useMemo(() => {
    if (!startDate) return undefined;
    const lastDayOfYear = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), 11, 31, 23, 59, 59);
    return lastDayOfYear;
  }, [startDate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setEndDate(startDate);
  }, [startDate]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>THE CODE DATEPICKER BY MONTH </p>
      <>
        <DatePicker
          calendarClassName="tren-pembayaran__wrapper__datepicker"
          showMonthYearPicker
          dateFormat="MM-yyyy"
          placeholderText="Tahun Awal"
          selected={startDate}
          minDate={new Date("2020")}
          onChange={setStartDate}
        />
        <DatePicker
          calendarClassName="tren-pembayaran__wrapper__datepicker"
          showMonthYearPicker
          dateFormat="MM-yyyy"
          placeholderText="Tahun Akhir"
          minDate={startDate}
          maxDate={startDateEndOfYear}
          selected={endDate}
          onChange={setEndDate}
          disabled={!startDate}
        />
      </>

      <p>THE DATEPICKER BY DATE </p>
      <>
        <DatePicker
          calendarClassName="tren-pembayaran__wrapper__datepicker"
          dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
          placeholderText="Tanggal Awal"
          selected={startDate}
          minDate={minStartDate}
          onChange={setStartDate}
        />
        <DatePicker
          calendarClassName="tren-pembayaran__wrapper__datepicker"
          dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
          placeholderText="Tanggal Akhir"
          minDate={startDate}
          maxDate={startDateEndOfMonth}
          selected={endDate}
          onChange={setEndDate}
          disabled={!startDate}
        />
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hardcore-ellis-6hosdr]

Comment: Thank you! It's works for that case. Anyway, can I use memo for another case? Example I choose month at "09-2021". So, any month in other year like 2022 will disable. Can I?

Comment: So, I have 3 date picker. First, by date. Second, by month. And last by year. If I choose to pick by month I enter value only MM-yyyy. For example, the startMonth I choose is "09-2021" and for the endMonth I want to disable other month in different year like 2020 or 2022

Comment: Done, I re-write your code on sandbox

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I didn't use sandbox before. I share you a link from my workspace

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-https-ld3155

Comment: I add some comments on my workspace. Hope it's can help you

Comment: @veronicanovianti Updated the answer and CodeSandbox. Check if it works for you please. If you have any questions - feel free to ask

Comment: Yeah! That's what I want to apply in my datepicker! Thank you so much @Sergey Sosunov you help me a lot